# Render a template in block without loading the whole page

Tags: django, templates, block

I have a template called base.html which looks simplified like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{% block title %} Title {% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        {% block header %}My Header{% endblock %}
    </div>

    <div class="navigation">
        {% block navigation %}My Navi{% endblock %}
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        {% block content %}Content{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i click on a link in the nav i want to render the new content in the content block without loading the header and navigation again.

Comment: You mean something like AJAX i.e. avoid the whole page refresh?

Comment: AJAX (maybe with backbone?)

Comment: principally yes but i would rather do something likes Frames in html where cou can load a now page just in a frame. I thought django would be able to do something like this in a very simple way. Or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of choices: Ajax or iFrames

If you go the Ajax route, you can render a template server-side and return the HTML in the Ajax response:

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def render_template(request):
    result = {'html': render_to_string('your-template.html', {})}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result, ensure_ascii=False),
        content_type='application/json')
```

Then you can use jQuery or whatever you want to update the HTML in the main page wherever you need.

Alternatively, you can use JavaScript to set the `src` of an iFrame on click to render a view without updating the entire page. It just depends on what's best for you in terms of user experience, maintenance, etc.

Comment: Yes, with AJAX you can use json responses, with it's a little faster that html responses, and using something like backbone or angular you can do it well

Comment: It seems that any `<script/>` tags are removed when a template is rendered via `render_to_string(...)`.

Comment: Actually it seems that if the template is rendered to string and that template `extends` another template, the script is lost from the rendered template (not from the template being extended). Strange. :/

Comment: I have no idea why that would be happening, as Django has no idea what a script tag is in a string. As a rule of thumb, I would never allow an arbitrary script tag to be executed in that fashion.