# Render block only in django with google app engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, templates, rendering, block

I'm using **google app engine** and **django** for running a simple web-application. Everything works fine, but when I'm clicking in my navigation on a link the whole page is rendering again, including the navigation. So I tried to except the main content with a block like that:

> ```
> # main.html
> <html>
> <title>Dummytitle</title>
> <body>
>
> ...Navigation menu...
>
> {% block maincontent %}
>
> {% endblock %}
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

And here the content:

> ```
> # index.html
> {% extends "main.html" %}
>
> {% block maincontent %}
>     <div id="main-container">
>        Amazing content 
>     </div>
> {% endblock %}
> ```

In the backend I'm calling the template like that:

> def render_template(self, view_filename = 'index.html', params=None):
>
> ```
>     path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'views', view_filename)
>
>     self.response.out.write(template.render(path, params))
> ```

But it still doesn't work. When I want to change the content from index.html to another page also the navigation itself is rendering again.

So how is it possible to change the content of the block without rendering the whole page?

Answer (score 0):

The full page (index with main, or another with main) is always rendered. Except when Jinja has cached  page data.

You can load a main and use ajax to load and change the page. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729111/django-render-a-template-in-block-without-loading-the-whole-page?rq=1)